# Store FCM Registration Token in SQL server

Tags: php, android, sql-server, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to store Firebase reg token in SQL database, the token appears in the logs, but doesn't send to the database.

Here is my "FirebaseInstanceIdService" class:

```
public class FirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d("REG_TOKEN",token);
    sendToken(token);
}

private void sendToken(String token) {
    OkHttpClient client =  new OkHttpClient();
    RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("Token",token)
            .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://192.168.1.6/fcm/addtoken.php")
            .post(body)
            .build();
    try {
        client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And this is the PHP script :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["Token"])) {
      $token=$_POST["Token"];
      $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fcm");
      $q="INSERT INTO users (Token) Values ( '$token') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Token = '$token';";

  mysqli_query($conn,$q) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
  mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you checked your PHP script on browser first?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. The reason why you're not receiving any results is because you're only calling `sendToken()` in `onTokenRefresh()`. This method is only triggered by [specific scenarios](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService#onTokenRefresh()), which is probably not being met.

Try calling `sendToken()` in your MainActivity's `onCreate()` method and see if a token is sent to your server.